# Interpreting Random v. Fixed-effect Difference-in-Difference equation (+Stata version)

Tags: econometrics, stata, difference-in-difference

When I compute:

```
xtset panelid year
xtreg y i.treat##i.post i.year
```

Versus:

```
xtset panelid year
xtreg y i.treat##i.post i.year, fe
```

**1.** What is the actual difference-in-differences (DiD) regression I'm calculating for each?

**2.** The coefficient `1.treat` should be for the treatment group-- do I need a control group dummy?

**3.** In the fixed effect model, `1.treat` is omitted due to collinearity, which is to be expected because it is being absorbed by the FE. Correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference-in-differences equation you are running is
$$
y_{it} = \alpha_i + \gamma \text{post}_t + \beta (treat_i \cdot post_t) + \epsilon_{it}
$$

where $\alpha_i$ are the individual fixed effects (which absorb the treatment dummy), $\text{post}_t$ is the post-treatment time dummy, and $\beta$ estimates your difference-in-differences parameter. When you type in Stata `i.treat##i.post` then this includes a dummy for `i1.treat`, `i1.post`, and their interaction `1.treat#1.post` which is equivalent to generating the corresponding dummies by hand and including them - though again the treatment indicator is unnecessary because it is going to be in $\alpha_i$.
You don't need a control dummy because treatment is either 0 or 1, hence a dummy for the control group would be perfectly collinear with the treatment dummy.

Your second specification is correct. Difference-in-differences is essentially a fixed effects regression using the within group variation in the outcomes pre- and post the intervention/treatment. In case you have multiple periods, you can accommodate for this by replace the post dummy with time dummies.

Comment: If I have the same treatment that occurs for two groups (a & b), and I calculate the beta using the fixed effect DiD equations here (second specification) for both groups combined (average treatment effect for a&b) versus a control, and then I calculate the beta or treatment effect of just one of the groups, group b, versus the control; can the difference in betas be interpreted as the multiplier on the treatment effect of remaining group a? i.e., combined treatment effect = .30. Treatment effect for group b = .32. So, the treatment is 1.06x as effective, on average, for group b?

Comment: Not sure how this relates to the original question but if a and b receive the same treatment then what makes them different? You can run your regressions separately for the sample using group and the control group, and for group b and the control group. If you run the difference-in-differences regression for the whole sample, the $\beta$ will be a weighted average of the treatment effects in the two groups.

Comment: @EconoQ did this answer your question?

Comment: It did, thank you. I do have multiple periods, so I should replace the post dummy with time dummies for t-2, t-1, t0, t+1, t+2

This would make the equation: 
`y=α+β(treat⋅post)+ γpost + calendarFE + groupFE + ϵ`

Which in Stata is:  
`xtset panelid time`
`xtreg y i.treat##i.post i.time i.calendaryear, fe`

I will get coefficients for each time period -- how is this typically reported?

Comment: I also added the follow-up here: [http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/268692/calendar-year-fe-versus-treatment-year-fe-in-difference-in-differences]